# How should we deal with homonyms in the tags?

Tags: discussion

I've been spending a little time adding definitions to the tags, and (actually completely by accident) came across this for "apple":

[image]

Which caused me to think that this issue might need to be brought to the attention of the community, as this may not be the only case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should deal with those on a case by case basis. In this case, do we *really* need a tag for apples? Somethings like the moon are the topic of many memes, but apples? Really?

Idem for Apple, actually. Do we need a tag for that?

Comment: Perhaps retagging the apple question with [tag:fruit] or [tag:food]?

Comment: For this one, I was thinking "apples" but there may be other such occurrences in the future, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

As Borror0 [said](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/928/how-should-we-deal-with-homonyms-in-the-tags/929#929) these particular cases can be handled by deleting the unnecessary tags.

If we do get a real clash of important tags, we can disambiguate both tags with extra words, and ask people to use one or the other: [apple-fruit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-fruit), [apple-computers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-computers), [apple-records](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-records)